# How can I merge these two lists

Tags: r

I am using R in Rstudio to merge two vectors. The two vectors are

```
Saturday_guests <- c("John","Amy", "Mike")
```

and

```
Sunday_guests <- c("Peter", "Adam", "Amy", "John")
```

I want to merge  `Saturday_guests`  and `Sunday_guests` to form 
`all_guests` which should equal `c(Peter,Adam,Amy,John,Mike)`

Comment: `unique(c(Sunday_guests, Saturday_guests))`

Comment: Those are not lists. They are vectors